# Im using IF statement with some condition if(user.length() != 0 && user.length()<20 && InputValidator.validateUser(user))

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators, boolean-expression

I am checking for some condition using `IF statement` like below:

Comment: What is the code inside validateUser()? Please share the complete code of the methods used here.

Comment: How do you verify and test "all the conditions are true"?

Comment: If statements are not loops.

Comment: answer cannot be provided until you check all separately and be sure that `InputValidator.validateUser(user)` is working fine as there is and condition added

Comment: I find that hard to believe

Comment: public static boolean validateUser(String user)
 {
  regex =Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9.'_-]*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        matcher= regex .matcher(user);
        System.out.println("USER=>"+matcher.find()+" "+user);
        return matcher.find();
 }

Comment: You are checking some conditions using one if statement. OK. What is the question?

Comment: I am checking 3 conditions using && and even though all conditions are true it is not entering the if loop

Comment: your if state ment must look like this:
`if (user.length() != 0 && user.length() < 20 && InputValidator.validateUser(user)) { system.out.println("It Works!"); } else { system.out.println("Bummer!"); }`
If your console doesn't print anything, you dont event get to the if statement. If it prints "Bummer!", try to replace each condition with `true` one by one until it prints "It Works!".
Eventually ending up with `if (true && true && true) { system.out.println("It Works!"); } else {system.out.println("Bummer!"); }`

Answer (score 1):

Run it in Eclipse with debug mode. In `Expressions` tab verify which condition is `false`. It's impossible in Java if all conditions are true and it will not go in `if block`. Make sure you have added `curly braces` if there are `multiline  statements` in `if block` and you have not added semicolon immediately after if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try separating them out and stepping through the code, for example just write:
if(user.length() != 0) 
{ go into loop }

then try 
if (user.length() < 20) 
{ go into loop }

then try 
if (InputValidator.validateUser(user))
{ go into loop }

to find which one of these is not evaluating to true.